# Is there a way to pause all sprites with a certain zPosition and below?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3

I am trying to pause a lot of sprites in my game. Is there a way that I can pause sprites which have a given `zPosition` or all sprites below a given `zPosition`? These sprites may also have physics bodies being update in the update method.

Comment: It is certainly possible. You have few options, if you know their zPosition before its creation, they you could put them into one parent and pause just parent. If you need to pause their physics bodies, the you must enumerate through nodes. Also if you cant have those nodes into a single parent, the do what is pointed in Alessandro's answer

Comment: @Whirlwind Great comment, I agree on everything.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano Also what you said, search by name can be used as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a code like this example  below to do this task:

```
self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//*") {
     node, stop in
     if node.zPosition > 1 && node.zPosition < 4 {
        // do whatever you want with these nodes (sprites, labels..)
        if node is SKSpriteNode { // you can use also this filter to pause only SKSpriteNode types
           node.isPaused = true
        }
     }
}
```

You can also decide to use a specific "**name**" instead of " * " in the first line to group only nodes with this name.